# Kubuntu wifi does not connect by default when I open my laptop

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, macbook-air

I am running the newest release of Kubuntu on my 2012 MacBook Air. When I close my laptop and then reopen it a few minute later, I am disconnected from WiFi, and the WiFi selection panel at the bottom-left-corner of my screen is blank, except for the "WiFi" switch and the "Airplane more" switch. The place that usually has all my WiFi networks is a blank white screen.

By the way, I am new to Kubuntu but have had experience with different Linux distributions in the past, so I know my way around Bash and stuff like that.

Wireless information:

```
  *-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:a0400000-a0403fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: wlp2s0b1
   serial: 28:cf:e9:4b:72:27                                                                                                             
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless                                                                                              
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=610.812 ip=##.#.#.# link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Comment: You are having problems with "Power Management". Read `man pm-action`, and figure out which script in `/etc/pm/*` needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Great! that solved it!